# Pyspark pivot data frame based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below.

```
df.show()

+---+-------+----+
| id|   type|s_id|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|    ios|  11|
|  1|    ios|  12|
|  1|    ios|  13|
|  1|    ios|  14|
|  1|android|  15|
|  1|android|  16|
|  1|android|  17|
|  2|    ios|  21|
|  2|android|  18|
+---+-------+----+
```

Now from this data frame I want to create another data frame by pivoting it.

```
df1.show()
+---+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| id| ios1| ios2| ios3| android1| android2| android3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|   11|   12|   13|       15|       16|       17|
|  2|   21| Null| Null|       18|     Null|     Null|
+---+-----+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Here I need to consider a condition that for each `Id` even though there will be more than `3` `types` I want to consider only `3 or less than 3`.

How can I do that?

> Edit

```
new_df.show()

+---+-------+----+
| id|   type|s_id|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|    ios|  11|
|  1|    ios|  12|
|  1|       |  13|
|  1|       |  14|
|  1|andriod|  15|
|  1|       |  16|
|  1|       |  17|
|  2|andriod|  18|
|  2|    ios|  21|
+---+-------+----+
```

The result I am getting is below

```
+---+----+----+----+--------+----+----+
| id|   1|   2|   3|andriod1|ios1|ios2|
+---+----+----+----+--------+----+----+
|  1|  13|  14|  16|      15|  11|  12|
|  2|null|null|null|      18|  21|null|
+---+----+----+----+--------+----+----+
```

What I want is

```
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
|id |android1|android2|android3|ios1|ios2|ios3|
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
|1  |15      |    null|    null|  11|  12|null|
|2  |18      |    null|    null|  21|null|null|
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following logic should get you your desired result.

`Window` function is used to generate *row number* for each group of `id` and `type` ordered by `s_id`. Generated row number is used to `filter` and `concat` with `type`. Then finally *grouping and pivoting* should give you your desired output

```
from pyspark.sql import Window 
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id", "type").orderBy("s_id")

from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn("ranks", f.row_number().over(windowSpec))\
    .filter(f.col("ranks") < 4)\
    .withColumn("type", f.concat(f.col("type"), f.col("ranks")))\
    .drop("ranks")\
    .groupBy("id")\
    .pivot("type")\
    .agg(f.first("s_id"))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
|id |android1|android2|android3|ios1|ios2|ios3|
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
|1  |15      |16      |17      |11  |12  |13  |
|2  |18      |null    |null    |21  |null|null|
+---+--------+--------+--------+----+----+----+
```

## answer for the edited part

You just *need an additional filter* as

```
df.withColumn("ranks", f.row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
    .filter(f.col("ranks") < 4) \
    .filter(f.col("type") != "") \
    .withColumn("type", f.concat(f.col("type"), f.col("ranks"))) \
    .drop("ranks") \
    .groupBy("id") \
    .pivot("type") \
    .agg(f.first("s_id")) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which would give you

```
+---+--------+----+----+
|id |andriod1|ios1|ios2|
+---+--------+----+----+
|1  |15      |11  |12  |
|2  |18      |21  |null|
+---+--------+----+----+
```

**Now this dataframe lacks `android2, android3 and ios3` columns. Because they are not present in your updated input data. you can add them using withColumn api and populate null values**

Comment: I am using `spark 1.6` and getting this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: _() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: I have made a small edit to my question please check the `edit` part of my question.

Comment: Please don't update the question once its been accepted as an answer because it will seem that the answer is not adequate enough for the question. You can always ask another question. For now I have updated the answer. but please don't do that in the future @user9367133